# Spark why does a worker automatically start on my master

Tags: apache-spark

I have 3 machines, one is the master and there are 2 slaves. I have the master address in spark/conf/masters and the two slaves in spark/conf/slaves.

I run `start-masters.sh` I have the GUI with no workers - all fine
Then I run `start-slaves.sh` and get my two slaves in the GUI - all fine

But when I start a job specifying the master URL with `--master spark://master` which is the same address in the masters file and is taken from the master's GUI, a worker starts on all machines.

Why? I do not want a worker on the master because the driver uses too much memory and cannot share the machine with a worker/executor. What am I doing wrong? Do I have to run a worker on the master? Should I move the master to one of the slaves and use the current master as a client to Spark?

Comment: Just curious if you have tried killing the worker manually with a ps and kill? Not an elegant solution, I wondered if the worker restarts. I am looking at the same problem if I find a good answer I'll post it.

Comment: Yes it restarts. I moved my master off the driver machine so it would be dedicated to running the driver and that seems to work. Now the master is also a worker. It takes about 1-1.5g to run the master but better than having a worker and driver on one machine, which uses 2x8g or more.

Comment: Yeah it's weird, I have followed through the various scripts that get called in $SPARK_HOME/sbin  when I run start-all.sh and start-slaves.sh, I can't see anywhere that it tries to start a slave anywhere that's not in that file slaves file. Must be in the source code for some reason ... gonna dig in there next, in a few days.